# Finding the second most optimal point using a modification of the simplex method

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, simplex-method, two-phase-simplex

So I was playing around with the simplex method and basically I was interested in solving the problem "find the second most optimal vertex" for maximizing a given objective function, to be concrete:

$$ \max c^T x $$

$$ Ax \le b$$

Where we assume the result is not infeasible/not-empty and also not unbounded.

So I have a somewhat inefficient way of doing this. I can

1. Run an algorithm of my choice (such as the simplex method) to identify the optimal extreme point for maximizing $c^Tx$
2. Now that I have this point $p$, I find which inequalities in $Ax \le b$ are tight for the point
3. Now that I know which inequalities are tight for the point (I'll have $n$ or more such inequalities) I can try every combination of $(n-1)$ inequalities from the tight set with one other inequality from the larger set and check

   1. if the resulting point is feasible,
   2. if it is feasible then calculate its objective and store these in a list $L$
4. With that list $L$ we find the point with largest objective value that isn't the first extreme point $p$.

So this awful strategy takes $O(\text{LP run time}) + nmO(\text{LP run time})$ to run.

Where $n$ is the dimension of the problem i.e. number of columns in $A$ (or said geometrically the dimension of the ambient space of our polytope)  and $m$ is the number of inequalities i.e. number of rows in $A$ (or said geometrically the  number  facets of our polytope).

I get the feeling that this procedure is kind of stupid and there should be a way to slightly modify the simplex method to basically find the extreme point and then do just one extra step to pivot to the 2nd from best extreme point. I am not sure what that procedure should be since the simplex method pivots on a per variable basis and doesn't let you directly say "take me to the vertex whose objective value is NEXT best".

Comment: Ralph E. Steuer, Multiple Criteria Optimization: Theory, Computation, and Application, Wiley, 1986 has a section on a pivoting algorithm for this.

Comment: I'm trying to get a library card with my local university to access the book. Would it be possible for you to provide the excerpt as an answer so I can accept it?